# Error querying Consul agent: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/vault?recurse=: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connect: connection refused

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

~]$ /apps/bin/consul/consul kv export vault

Error querying Consul agent: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/vault?recurse=: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connect: connection refused

I'm trying to export entire vault/ folder from consul.

seeing the below error

Error querying Consul agent: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/vault?recurse=: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the http/s address of [Consul agent](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html) to which you're trying to connect. The default one is `http://127.0.0.1:8500` and it doesn't work as you can see in the error.

To do this, set the following environment variable using the `export` command:

```
export CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR = <http/s_address_to_consul_agent>
```

If connecting via TLS, set also:

```
export CONSUL_CACERT = <path_to_cert_file>
```

**Alternatively**, you can set the above values as the [parameters](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/kv/export.html) to `consul kv export` command:

```
consul kv export -http-addr=<http/s_address_to_consul_agent> -ca-file=<path_to_cert_file>
```